# How can we move linux process to different memory area than one it is created

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Here is a requirement for one of my project.
I need to move the entire linux process into different memory location after the process creation.
Quite confused from where to start either at the end of dofork in fork.c or somewhere else.
And some where i am thinking will the process still work the same way if it is moved to other memory location.

Expecting some help to do this task.

Thanks

Comment: What is the purpose of moving?

Comment: Idea is to hide the process data from the root user or kernel

Comment: Hide from kernel - what do you mean, - trustzone?